# d3.js data join shows strange result

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3v4 and within the html document I have 20 g.node elements, with 4 having the value: d.nameY === "responded No".

The following statement works correct:

```
d3.select("g.sankeyFrame.single")
            .selectAll("g.node")
            .filter( function(d) { return d.nameY === "responded No";})
            .size();
```

It returns 4 as desired.

However, the following data join doesn't return the expected selection:

```
d3.select("g.sankeyFrame.single")
            .selectAll("g.node")
            .data(["responded No"], function(d){ return d.nameY;})
            .size();
```

It returns 0, it should return all 4 g.node elements, where d.nameY === 4.

What possible reason prevents the data join from working? 
(The code base is too large to publish here)

Comment: Your code is attempting to find a property called `nameY` on a plain string. And even if you did `.data([{ nameY: "responded No" }]`, the size of the update selection would be 1, not 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What possible reason prevents the data join from working?

No reason at all. It **is** working. And the result is not wrong, that's the expected behaviour. You have another problem here.

To show you the problem, let's create a very simple demo, which appends 20 `<div>`s, 4 of them with the datum `"foo"`. Here is the code using your first approach, with `filter`:

```js
var p = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(20).map(function(d) {
    return d < 4 ? "foo" : "bar"
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(String);

var filtering = d3.selectAll("div")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d === "foo"
  }).size();

console.log("size is: " + filtering)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now let's see your second approach:

```
d3.select("g.sankeyFrame.single")
        .selectAll("g.node")
        .data(["responded No"], function(d){ return d.nameY;})
        .size();
```

You have two problems here:

1. The key function will not work. There is no property `nameY` in a simple, flat array like `["responded No"]`. That's why your selection's size is `0`.
2. There is just **one** element in that array. So, even if you remove the wrong key function, that selection will have just **one** element. Let's prove it:

```js
var p = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(20).map(function(d) {
    return d < 4 ? "foo" : "bar"
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(String);

var dataBinding = d3.selectAll("div")
  .data(["baz"])
  .size();

console.log("size is: " + dataBinding)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

That point #2 is the most important here: the size of the update selection returned by `data()` is the size of its array.

Finally, to clearly show that the `data()` is working, let's see the datum of each `<div>`:

```js
var p = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(20).map(function(d) {
    return d < 4 ? "foo" : "bar"
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(String);

var dataBinding = d3.selectAll("div")
  .data(["baz"])
  .size();

d3.selectAll("div").each(function(d, i) {
  console.log("div number " + i + " - datum: " + d)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: P.s. you seem to intend using data([„foo“]) not „baz“

Comment: No, I indeed mean to use `baz`, just for you to see that the datum changed.

Comment: Oh, ok ! One thing I missed (among others) is that the key function of the data join is equally applied to the elements as well as to the data Array.