# How to use a value in d3 data key function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is on d3 v5.

D3 doesn't seem to recognize a value in key function for me. For e.g.

```js
// first create 5 elements
var data = d3.range(0,5);
var g = d3.select('svg')
  .append('g').selectAll("text")
  .data(data, d=>d+"_a");  // append value "a"

console.log(`new ${g.enter().size()} update ${g.size()} exit ${g.exit().size()}`);

// do some dummy stuff
g.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("id", d=>d+"_a");

var data = [1,2];
var g = d3.selectAll('text')
  .data(data, d=>d+"_b");  // append a different value "b"

// shouldn't this show: new 2 update 0 exit 5?
console.log(`new ${g.enter().size()} update ${g.size()} exit ${g.exit().size()}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=100 height=100> </svg>
```

Is it possible to add a "value" when defining the key function? Or it has to only come from the data?

Answer (score 0):

The key function is solely there for comparison. It compares the data referenced in the key function with the data bound to elements based on the key function as well.
You cannot add a value within the key function.

See also: 
https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data

There the official documentation says:

> A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to
>   which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing a
>   string identifier for each datum and element. This key function is
>   evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the
>   current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group
>   (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]); the returned
>   string is the element’s key. The key function is then also evaluated
>   for each new datum in data, being passed the current datum (d), the
>   current index (i), and the group’s new data, with this as the group’s
>   parent DOM element; the returned string is the datum’s key. The datum
>   for a given key is assigned to the element with the matching key. If
>   multiple elements have the same key, the duplicate elements are put
>   into the exit selection; if multiple data have the same key, the
>   duplicate data are put into the enter selection.

Looking at your example:

```
var data = d3.range(0,5);
var g = d3.select('svg')
  .append('g').selectAll("text")
  .data(data, d=>d+"_a");
// the g selection is joined with [0,1,2,3,4]
// the key function doesn't find a match with elements (there is none anyway)
// so g.enter() contains a placeholder for 5 elements
// which will be joined with 0,1,2,3,4 respectively

// do some dummy stuff
g.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("id", d=>d+"_a");

var data = [1,2];
var g = d3.selectAll('text')
  .data(data, d=>d+"_b");  
// now the 5 elements are joined with the Array [1,2]
// The key function looks for data which concatenated with "_b" matches
// with the data bound to the elements.
// So it essentially compares the data from the array with the data bound to the elements. 
// A simpler way to write the key function is
// .data(data, d => d)
// which is a common d3.js join pattern.
// Thus, the second and third <text> element match
// this condition and end up in the update selection
```

A helpful SO answer is also here:
[d3.js data join shows strange result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128363/d3-js-data-join-shows-strange-result)